# Data Scraping from Website - receiving error on different player pages

Tags: vba

I'm trying to data scrape game logs from basketball reference.com. It worked perfectly on two players I choose (demar derozan and lamarcus aldridge). But then I started going through other players and it just wouldn't scrape the data for many of the other players (Kevin Durant).

I have NO Idea why it wouldn't work. For example, I tried Stephen Curry and it worked fine, but players like Draymond Green and Kevin Durant, the code would just not scrape the data at all. For some reason after the column Date, everything stopped working.

```
Sub Data()
    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1

    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    ieObj.Visible = True
    ieObj.navigate "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/d/duranke01/gamelog/2019"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("stats_table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")

        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
            .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent
            .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent

        End With

    i = i + 1
    On Error Resume Next

    Next htmlEle

End Sub
```

The error always happens on this line: 
.Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent

I tried skipping columns to but it still wouldn't work.

Comment: Strange, I did check couldn't find an issue with the DOM which would prevent that from happening. Though I'm more comfortable with Selenium/BeautifulScript and Python (which btw you should try instead of VBA) so maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no problem with using id for table, as seen in `.responseText` and using [xmlhttp](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) over browser.

I only tested with 3 urls - in sheet 1 A1:A3

1. https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/d/duranke01/gamelog/2019
2. https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/curryst01/gamelog/2019
3. https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/g/greendr01/gamelog/2019

With this site sometimes you can encounter tables inside comments so I stripped out the comment tags before processing. This was not necessary for the links I tried.

I use clipboard to copy paste but you could just use

```
Set hTable = html.getElementById("pgl_basic")
```

Then loop the `tr` and `td` as you wish using `getElementsByTagName`.

---

**References (VBE>Tools>References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetPlayerInfo()
    Dim urls(), i As Long, html As HTMLDocument, hTable As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsCurrent As Object, clipboard As Object
    Dim lastRow As Long, playerIdentifier As String, arr() As String

    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    urls = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value)
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)
            .Open "GET", urls(i), False
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = Replace$(Replace$(.responseText, "-->", vbNullString), "<!--", vbNullString) 'remove comments
            arr = Split(urls(i), "/")
            playerIdentifier = arr(5)
            If SheetExists(playerIdentifier) Then
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(playerIdentifier).Cells
                    .ClearContents
                    .ClearFormats
                    Set wsCurrent = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(playerIdentifier)
                End With
            Else
                 Set wsCurrent = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
                 wsCurrent.name = playerIdentifier
            End If
            Set hTable = html.querySelector("#pgl_basic")
            clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
            clipboard.PutInClipboard
            wsCurrent.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
            Set wsCurrent = Nothing: Set hTable = Nothing: Erase arr: playerIdentifier = vbNullString
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Public Function SheetExists(ByVal sheetName As String) As Boolean '<==  function by @Rory
    SheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sheetName & "'!A1)")
End Function
```

---

**IE**

Note proper page load wait used.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetPlayerInfo()
    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer, htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim urls(), i As Long, j As Long, hTable As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsCurrent As Object
    Dim lastRow As Long, playerIdentifier As String, arr() As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo errHand
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    urls = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value)

    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    With ieObj
        .Visible = True
        For j = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)
            .navigate urls(j)
            While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
            arr = Split(urls(j), "/")
            playerIdentifier = arr(5)
            If SheetExists(playerIdentifier) Then
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(playerIdentifier).Cells
                    .ClearContents
                    .ClearFormats
                    Set wsCurrent = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(playerIdentifier)
                End With
            Else
                Set wsCurrent = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
                wsCurrent.Name = playerIdentifier
            End If
            i = 1
            Set hTable = .document.getElementById("pgl_basic")
            If Not hTable Is Nothing Then
                For Each htmlEle In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                    With wsCurrent
                        .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
                        .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
                        .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent
                        .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
                    End With
                    i = i + 1
                Next htmlEle
            End If
            Set wsCurrent = Nothing: Set hTable = Nothing: Erase arr: playerIdentifier = vbNullString
        Next
    End With
errHand:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: The First method loads so much faster than the second. What is the main difference.

Comment: the first method doesn't launch a browser. So you don't have that overhead or the time it takes for rendering content. Downside, you don't get rendered content but that doesn't matter in this case.