# VBA: Web scraping with <ul and <li and <div and <span

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am using VBA to extract the data from HTML in `<span` code which is under `<Div` which is under `<li` which is under `<ul`

I'm trying to extract the "date and matter" from HTML. "Date" should be in A column and "Matter" should be in B Column in Excel.

The drawback of my code is, it is pulling all the `Date` and `matter` into single cell.

```
Sub GetDat()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, data As String

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.MyURL/sc/wo/Worders/index?id=76888564"
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    data = ""

    For Each elem In html.getElementsByClassName("simple-list")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")
        data = data & " " & elem.innerText
    Next elem

    Range("A1").Value = data

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

The output that I need is shown in the image:

HTML:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could grab two nodeLists, one for dates and one for matters, and then loop those writing out to sheet. Match `dates` based on `data-bind` attribute value; `matters` on `classname`:

```
Dim dates As Object, matters As Object, i As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set dates = ie.document.querySelectorAll("[data-bind^='text:createdDate']") '.wo-notes-col-1 [data-bind^='text:createdDate']
Set matters = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".wo-notes")

With ws

    For i = 0 To dates.Length - 1
        .Cells(i + 1, 1) = dates.Item(i).innertext
        .Cells(i + 1, 2) = matters.Item(i).innertext
    Next

End With
```

---

Example reading values from column C:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetMatters()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, urls(), results(), ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, r As Long

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    urls = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("C2:C" & lastRow).Value)
    ReDim results(1 To 1000, 1 To 2)

    With ie
        .Visible = True

        For i = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)
            .navigate2 "https://www.MyURL/sc/wo/Worders/index?id=" & urls(i)
            While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

            Dim dates As Object, matters As Object, i As Long

            Set dates = .document.querySelectorAll("[data-bind^='text:createdDate']") '.wo-notes-col-1 [data-bind^='text:createdDate']
            Set matters = .document.querySelectorAll(".wo-notes")

            For i = 0 To dates.Length - 1
                r = r + 1
                results(r, 1) = dates.Item(i).innertext
                results(r, 2) = matters.Item(i).innertext
            Next
            Set dates = Nothing: Set matter = dates
        Next
        .Quit
    End With

    ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End Sub
```

---

**References:**

1. [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectoraLL)
2. [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: Thanks QHarr, for taking some time to solve my problem. Could you please help me for looping the code for several times.

Comment: What do you mean looping code for several times? Does the above write out the table as expected?

Comment: Means the number that i have mentioned in URL 76888564 will change frequenlty. That means i need to work with this macro for multiple numbers (WorkOrders). Is it possible to loop for multiple workorders. Sorry for the inconvenience cause. Thanks

Comment: where are these new results going to go for different work orders?

Comment: you want a loop similar construction to as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57234600/6241235

Comment: Hi QHarr, i have attached the output file that i need on the top of this page. Please kindly look at it once. Thanks

Comment: Thanks alot QHarr, for your selfless help in this macro code. Have a great day..

Comment: Hi QHarr, Your code is i what i need, but it is repeating twice for every work order how can i solve that.
For example: for work order 76888564 there are 3 results. the output that i get if 6 results. the work order 76888564 is repeting twice and hence i see mutiple results.

Comment: without seeing the relevant html hard to advise but it is likely that you need to many nodes are being matched by the css selector.  After this line, for example, _Set dates = .document.querySelectorAll("[data-bind^='text:createdDate']")_  add a new line of _MsgBox dates.length_ and check if this is the expected number of dates?

Comment: Yes QHarr, what you said is correct using "MsgBox dates.length" it is showing 12 where for that work-order it has only 6 dates.

Comment: QHarr, What i understood is there are two <ul class codes with name "simple-list". The above html code which i send is the second <ul class code (ie., second "simple list"). can you just modify the code to search second <ul class code ie., "simple list". I think with this it is going to solve the problem.

Comment: What happens when you do _Msgbox ie.document.querySelectorAll(".wo-notes-col-1 [data-bind^='text:createdDate']").length_ ?

Comment: You could pastebin.com a link with entire html then I can check what css combination I need to use.

Comment: Hi QHarr, Sorry i dont have rights to sent entire code. so could you clarify me how to select second element in the html code.
 For ex: i have two <ul class= "simple-list"> class codes. But i want to select the second <ul class= "simple-list"> with that i need to continue vba code which you have mentioned. Is it possible to do so.

Comment: It would help to know how the two nodes are related to each other in the HTML tree structure. I guess at a push you could use ie.document.querySelectorAll(".simple-list").item(1)  and then transfer the outerHTML of that node to a new HTMLDocument or use .children etc to work of that node.

Comment: kindly, can you modify the code in the first vba that you have listed above, because i couldn't get the point .children.

Comment: Hi HQarr, Thanks a lot this is what the code i needed, you where sooo helpful in this macro. 
I struggled alot for the line
"html.body.innerHTML = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".simple-list").Item(1).outerHTML"
But you solved the problem. Thanks a lot again for you selfless help. And i'm really sorry for giving you lot of trouble in this regard.

HQarr, is there anything that i need to do from my end.

Comment: Not a problem. Happy to help. :-)